# How to model nested resources using RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested-resources, rabl, view-templates

I want to setup a nested route in my Rails project as illustrated here:

```
# config/routes.rb
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :places, only: [:index]
      resources :users do
        resource :places
      end
    end
  end
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

I use [RABL templates](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to render JSON contents. It might be that I misunderstand the purpose of `child` elements in RABL. As far as I understand they will not lead me to a RESTful path as show below. On the other hand please tell me if RABL does not support nested resources.

How can I output JSON for a nested route such as ... ? How can I write a RABL template which matches the route `users/:id/places`?

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/13/places.json
```

I do **not** want to display the user information. It should **not** be possible to retrieve user data via the following paths:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/13.json
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users.json
```

In the project I use [CanCan 1.6.9.](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) and [Devise 2.2.3.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar using before filters in the controller.

```
class Api::PlacesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :find_user

def index
    if @user 
        @places = @user.places
    else
        ...    
    end
end

private

def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
end
```

Then in api/places/index.json.rabl

```
collection @places
attributes :id, :name, etc
```

Comment: But does this actually provide a nested route such as `users/:id/places`? I do not want to overwrite the default behaviour of the `index` action.